# didUpdate pushCredentials method is called slowly?

Tags: ios, swift, push-notification

In our application what we do is if push notification is enabled then we send token to our server. But sendTokenId() is called before didUpdate pushCredentials.Why this is happening?
 When sendTokenId() is performed tokenId is nil. After some time push credentials is updated.That time tokenId is present.

```
   func pushRegistry(_ registry: PKPushRegistry, didUpdate pushCredentials: PKPushCredentials, for type: PKPushType)
    {

      \\ code to get tokenId
    }
```

```
    func sendTokenId()
    {
        \\ code to send token to server
    }
```

Anyone please help me to fix this.Thanks in advance.

Comment: how and when are you calling `sendTokenId`?

Comment: @SandeepBhandari. When Login I check whether app supports push notification. If it is yes then I send token to our server. That time token id is nil. After sometime only tokenId is updated.

Comment: Why don't you call `sendTokenId` after `didUpdate pushCredentials` is triggered? I mean call `sendTokenId ` inside `didUpdate pushCredentials` not on app launch

Comment: I have edited my answer to clarify your doubts, read it and if it helps please consider accepting the answer

Answer (score 1):

`didUpdate pushCredentials` is a delegate method of `PKPushRegistryDelegate` protocol. There is a reason why its made a delegate method, because device token generation is a **asynchronous task**, when your app registers for notification by creating `PKPushRegistry` and by specifying `desiredPushTypes` iOS talks to APNS service to generate a unique device token, on receiving a valid device token iOS delivers it your app by calling the appropriate delegate method in your code, which you then communicate it back to your server and your server uses it to send notification to specific device.

Quoting [Apple docs](https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/NetworkingInternet/Conceptual/RemoteNotificationsPG/HandlingRemoteNotifications.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40008194-CH6-SW3)

> Each time your app launches, it must register with APNs. The methods
>   to use differ according to the platform, but in all cases it works as
>   follows:
>
> 1. Your app asks to be registered with APNs.
> 2. On successful registration,APNs sends an app-specific device token
>      to the device.
> 3. The system delivers the device to your app by calling a method in
>      your app  delegate.
> 4. Your app sends the device token to the app’s
>      associated provider.

Finally, as per your question is concerned,

> didUpdate pushCredentials method is called slowly?

Its not getting called slowly, its being Called asynchronously as it has been designed to do that :)

So change your code to,

```
  func pushRegistry(_ registry: PKPushRegistry, didUpdate pushCredentials: PKPushCredentials, for type: PKPushType)
    {
        //get token here from pushCredentials
        // call sendTokenId
        self.sendTokenId(pass_token_you_recieved)
    }
```

```
    func sendTokenId(_ tokenId: Data)
    {
        \\ code to send token to server
    }
```

Hope this helps